# What is the best unicode library for .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode

.NET does not supports many features of Unicode. It supports some basic features.

What is the best unicode library for .NET?

**Edit**:

I mean some thing like icu project:

http://icu-project.org

icu does not supports .NET, it supports Java.

Comment: I have _never_ needed more than what the framework provides. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: Can you specify which features you are missing. From my part .NET is very friendly to non-latin cultures. All controls native to .NET support unicode. Some Win32 might not.

Comment: What exactly is there in icu that is missing in the framework?

Comment: @oded: for example character properties, some thing like character name, BidiMirroring, and all fields of UCD.

Comment: Are you sure Bidi Mirroring is not supported?  Was discussed on MSDN 4 years ago... http://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/postlist.aspx?WeblogApp=michkap&y=2007&m=08&d=1&GroupKeys=&PageIndex=3&PostSortBy=MostViewed

Comment: @oded. In which Winform Controls except WebView or WebControl is it possible to display correclty (with colors) a character greater than 0xFFFF ?

Answer (score 7):

> What is the best unicode library for .NET?

The [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) itself.